How rotate instances to align with wall on geometry nodes
I'm making a procedural rock wall, the problem is that I can't make the columns align to the wall:

Some columns are aligned but after a turn they continue to face the same direction. The base geometry for the geo nodes is just a basic mesh:

In the geo nodes, I basically just add a cube to vertices that I asign to a vertex group, which are where columns are suppose to be. In other words, columns are placed on vertices as you can see:

These are the geo nodes:

Basically just placing a cuboid on the selected vertices, but I have no idea how to fix the orientation.

To be able to align the pillars along the wall, you would need to know the direction in which the faces of the wall are pointing.
However, since a vertex group is the basis for instantiation in your case, you can also do this using the edges that emerge from your selection.
You solve this by first separating the edges from the geometry.
Next, you capture the direction in which these edges point in the edge domain.
Starting from the original mesh, you then get this direction in which the edges point with Sample Nearest and transform this direction with Align Euler to Vector into a rotation, which you can apply directly when instantiating the columns.
The setup then looks something like this:

(Blender 4.1.1+)

Thanks! That worked perfectly!
